# Is there a way to import json template files and use them on a page with Elementor from code?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to dynamically set up some pages on a WordPress site using a bash script. I would like the pages to use Elementor, so future users can configure them easily. 
I have already figured out that I can set the page template via an SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO
wp_postmeta
(post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES
(4, '_wp_page_template', 'elementor_canvas');
```

I would like to import (and also insert) json template files (exported from another Elementor page).

I have had a look on https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/881 and I found this code (from @crazypsycho):

```
function importTemplate( $filepath ) {
    $fileContent = file_get_contents( $filepath );
    $fileJson = json_decode( $fileContent, true );

    $result = \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->templates_manager->import_template( [
            'fileData' => base64_encode( $fileContent ),
            'fileName' => 'test.json',
        ]
    );

    if ( empty( $result ) || empty( $result[0] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    update_post_meta( $result[0]['template_id'], '_elementor_location', 'myCustomLocation' );
    update_post_meta( $result[0]['template_id'], '_elementor_conditions', [ 'include/general' ] );
}
```

I do not understand where to put this code and how to execute it, where to put my json template files and how to display them on a post. Wp-cli and Elementor's integration to it was not too helpful to me, the `import_library` function caused permission errors.

I have also looked at the changes in the db when importing a template and I have found that it adds some values in the `wp_postmeta` table. However, when I tried to recreate it, the page did not change at all.

**I am looking for the easiest way to accomplish importing and inserting json Elementor template files to the site from code.**

If anyone could explain how Elementor works (as for its structure), why I see no .json files in the site folder (using `find` command) after an import, or give me any guidance on where should I look, that would already be greatly appreciated. 
(Google is really not helpful in this problem as it mostly shows stuff on how to do this via the GUI).

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you wish to import JSON templates on the bash command line and not us the GUI template import method?  I have noticed that the JSON files are not retained after the template is imported.  Hence, the reason you cannot find and files.

Comment: Yes! I want to import the json templates without using the gui.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on the same issue and found the following solution with curl:

1. Log into wordpress
2. Upload **elementor-kit.zip**
3. Confirm import ('activate')

```
#!/bin/bash

# get an admin session cookie (adapt user/pwd as needed)
admin_page=$(curl -L --data 'log=ADMINUSER&pwd=ADMINPASSWORD'  -c wpcookie.txt 'https://{wordpress-url}/wp-login.php')

wp_nonce=$(grep -oPm1 "action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=\K[^']+" <<<$admin_page)
el_nonce=$(grep -oPm1 'var elementorCommonConfig.*"nonce":"\K[^"]+' <<<$admin_page)

echo wp_nonce $wp_nonce
echo el_nonce $el_nonce
echo Upload...
rval=$(curl '{wordpress-url}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' \
  -H "X-WP-NONCE: $wp_nonce" \
  -F action='elementor_import_kit' \
  -F "e_import_file=@elementor-kit.zip;type=application/zip" \
  -F data='{"stage":1}' \
  -F _nonce="$el_nonce" \
  -b wpcookie.txt)

data=$(jq -r '.data' <<< "$rval" )
session=$(jq -r '.session' <<< "$data" )

echo Activate... 
 curl '{wordpress-url}/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' \
  -H "X-WP-NONCE: $wp_nonce" \
  -F action='elementor_import_kit' \
  -F data='{"stage":2, "session":'"\"$session\""',"include": ["settings","content","templates"],"overrideConditions":[]}' \
  -F _nonce="$el_nonce" \
  -b wpcookie.txt \
  -o output.txt
```

Note that elementor seems to have some issues if you import the kit into a different site, not all posts get linked correctly to the new post-id...